# Rails Debug - How to print variable values on every step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rdebug

Say I have a variable called `@test_var`

And I have hundred lines of code using this variable

On debugging I need to give `n` for next step and `@test_var` to check the value

Can I do both in single command (i.e) print the value of a variable on every step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
display @test_var
```

After that, `@test_var` will be printed every time the debugger stops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it in controller then

for each line give one heading like

```
p "step 1"
p @test_var

p "step 2"
p @test_var
```

Comment: Well I gave that case for example, but the real situation is in production with tons of code

Comment: we can divided tons of code into multiple methods, also we can take use of helpers. If it is not an old code, then its good to divided into multiple private methods as per their usuability.

Comment: Are you telling to add `print` to every line ?

Comment: Not mandatory to give print to every line.. hope u could think from a shorter part of the code where the @variable value may change and print there

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to print and debug variables is https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/wrapped_print

you can simply call `@test_var.wp`  to see in the logs a value of this variable